# MQTT as an addition to the REST API

Tags: rest, api, mqtt

I have a REST API which receives some information (let's say `events`) from clients. Now I need to send some information from the server to clients. I'm trying to add MQTT as an additional way for clients to communicate with the server. Unlike HTTP MQTT allows me to do both: sending and receiving, so it's possible to make MQTT analogs for all existing REST API methods.

1. Receive `events` from clients - **HTTP**, **MQTT**
2. Sent `commands` to clients - **MQTT**

My idea was to make a "listener" which subscribes to all "event" MQTT topics and translate them into HTTP requests to the REST API (to keep components decoupled). But there is a problem: this listener is a simple client. It doesn't have any special permissions and can't get publisher's credentials to act on his behalf when talking with the REST API. MQTT doesn't even allow a subscriber to get who published a particular message.

One solution is to use MQTT only for sending information from the server to clients and keep using REST API for all incoming requests. But that looks strange :)

Another way is to use broker custom hooks but not all brokers support it and it's not a part of the MQTT specification so it's not very reliable.

Any ideas how to organize it in a proper way?

Answer (score 1):

Given that most (if not all) MQTT brokers support wildcard topics in ACLs you can encode the user in the topic and then grant the agent access to the wild card topic that matches all users.

e.g.

publish to `events/<user>`

and then grant the agent access to the topic `events/+`

You can then make sure that the Users ACL makes sure only they can publish to `events/<user>` such ensuring that users can not impersonate each other.

Comment: The REST API needs a JWT token. I'm afraid it's too long to put it into the topic name.